# POCO raise event on TCPServer connected threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, events, tcpserver, poco-libraries

I'm new to Poco framework and not to good with C++ but I am learning. I have to create a server-client based application in windows. 
The problem that I have now is that I need to send repeatedly from minute to minute some data to the clients. i need to do this for the clients that have an active tcp connection with the server. I don't know how can I create an event, or something that is triggered in a thread and starts all the active threads to send data to the clients. 
My first idea is that I have to rewrite, or extend the TCPServerDispatcher Class. And I don't know how can I identify the active threads from the ThreadPool.

Do you have any ideas, or maybe suggestions, or a tutorial, something? 
I can't figure it out how to do it...

Hope somebody can give me an idea, or some code example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can these server<> client threads not obtain the data for themselves?  It would be fairly easy to add a 60-second timeout on a read() in each thread and send the data then.  Maybe this would involve too many database connections?

Failing that, can you put the latest data in a lockable object and have the threads just lock, write and unlock the latest data on a timeout?  Such a solution should really have a write timeout as well to prevent a badly-behaved client causing its server thread to block while holding the lock.  If it's not too large, I suppose the server<> client thread could make a copy of the data to send, but I'm not a great fan of copying, TBH.

There are more complex ways of signaling the server<> client threads that new data is avalable. It is quite possible to signal each thread that new data is available and have them act upon it 'immediately'.  This usually means the server<> client thread waiting on more than one signal.  In general, the lower the latency, the more complex the solution:(

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: Well, the increased number of database connections is the problem. I need to make it as less frequent as possible.